# Could Spring decode @ModelAttribute if it contains Long field or is a Map instance?

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa, model, attributes

Is any other way than `@SessionAttributes("entitytopass")` to pass java object:

from POST method of "form" servlet / controller ->

-> to the "display" one,

if it contains Long field or is Map instance?

After many attempts, using `RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes` to pass `Entity entity`, ex:

```
  redirectAttributes.addAttribute("entitytopass", entity);
```

I was surprised to find that it persistently parses the field from Long to Integer one. This results in a failure to build the received object in the receiving servlet. So, method as below is not successful and throws `TypeMismatchException` :

```
@RequestMapping(value ="/display", method = RequestMethod.GET)  
 public String add(@ModelAttribute("entitytopass") Entity entityreceived, Model model) {  
    model.addAttribute("entitypresented", entityreceived);
  return "/displaypage";  // displaypage.jsp would present saved values  
 }
```

Spring Error report after `Entity entityreceived` decoding would be:

```
Failed to convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'some.domain.jpa.model.Entity'; 
nested exception is org.springframework.core.convert.ConversionFailedException: Failed to convert from type [java.lang.String] to type [@org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute some.domain.jpa.model.Entity] for value '0'; 
nested exception is org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: Provided id of the wrong type for class some.domain.jpa.model.Entity. Expected: class java.lang.Long, got class java.lang.Integer; 
nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Provided id of the wrong type for class some.domain.jpa.model.Entity. Expected: class java.lang.Long, got class java.lang.Integer
```

the same happans if entity would be `Map<String,String>` instance, although the objects transferred and extracted from the session are encoded and decoded without any problem beetween servlets / controllers.

-- edit --

Entity is symbolic, but ex.

```
public class Entity extends BaseEntity implements Serializable, EntityLabels {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -3776095967033917869L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "addr_id")
    private long addressId;

    @Column(updatable = true, name = "addr_name", nullable = true, length = 50)
    private String addressName;

    @Column(updatable = true, name = "city", nullable = false, length = 50)
    private String city;

    @Column(updatable = true, name = "post_cod", nullable = false, length = 6)
    private String postalCode;

    @Column(updatable = true, name = "street", nullable = false, length = 50)
    private String streetName;

    @Column(updatable = true, name = "str_no", nullable = false, length = 6)
    private String streetNumber;

    @Column(updatable = true, name = "flat_no", nullable = true, length = 6)
    private String flatNumber;

    @ColumnDefault(value = "'Poland'")
    @Column(updatable = true, name = "country", nullable = false, length = 50)
    private String country; // = "Poland";

    // standard constructor
    public Entity() {
    }

    // getters & setters

}
```

Comment: Can you add the code for `Entity`?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like spring framework need Entity but you are providing String

You should declare java model class not Entity

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).